# Format String to show it evenly

Tags: java

I am retrieving information from two separate `ArrayList<String>`s (both have the same length) to be displayed. Is there anyway I can tabulate it to show neatly? Because the length of the String is going to vary and there is no way for me to pre-determine the length.

This is how it currently looks.

```
Title Quantity

name1 10
name2 20
namenamename 30
na 40
```

I am trying to obtain the following by making it adjust accordingly to the length.

```
Title         Quantity

name1         10
name2         20
namenamename  30
na            40
```

Code

```
String order = "Title:\tQuantity\n";
for(int x=0; x < list1.size(); x++){
    order += list1.get(x) + "\t\t" + list2.get(x) + "\n";
}
```

New Code

```
String order = String.format("%-30s %s", "Title", "Quantity\n");
for(int x=0; x < list1.size(); x++){
    order+= String.format("%-30s %s", list1.get(x), list2.get(x)) + "\n";
}
```

How it looks now

```
Title                    Quantity

Crackers                 4
Cup                     6
Desk                   1
Fanta Soft Drink            12
Oasis Citrus Punch            1
Oreo Double Stuff             22
Spinach                 1
```

Comment: Don't use tabs, use `String.format(...)` or `System.out.printf(...)`, which both use the same formatter.

Comment: This is only true for mono-spaced fonts. If you aren't using a mono-spaced font, then you won't be able to use the approach given in the 'duplicate' answer. (Just an FYI)

Comment: That's some extreme urgency shown to close a question before I could even test out to see if it answers my query. I have edited and added my adjusted code according to the answers. Same results when the data is not aligned as before.

Comment: To "poke" Hovercraft use the @ annotation, seeing as it was he who marked it as a dupe. @HovercraftFullOfEels like that. However I agree with him. So I doubt he will open it up again.

Comment: Problem you are doing now is not following what he said / what the post said, you are using a new format for every `String` you are appending. Do one format and use that one for multiple lines of `System.out.printf(...)`

Comment: @Emz I am not printing these out. After formatting it, I am sending this string over to an email thus not using printf. Little confused since the format I am using is the same regardless whether I used it once or multiple times in a loop. Mind showing me an example in this instance.

Answer (score 1):

Find the longest entry for the first column, then use `String.format()` with a format string with field width parameter like so: `%-23s %4s` should create you two columns, where c1 is 23 wide, left justified. c2 is 4 chars right justified.

see the duplicate question and here https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax

Comment: My c1 is aligned fine using ur suggestion but c2 is still not aligned and my c1 max length doesn't go beyond 15 in my testing.

Comment: @cubeb in your examples c2 is always 2 digits, add different example(s) to show what "c2 is still not aligned" means...

Comment: c2 can be between 1 - 1000. Edited above to show how it looks now exactly.

Comment: Tried with %4s and same result. I'll take a look at the documentation and see if anything else pops out. Thanks.

Comment: Are your strings possibly with spaces? Or do you use a proportional font?

Comment: @thst String at c1 is possible with spaces. c2 isn't.